# Is there any method to convert python to executable without python python interpreter inside

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation, executable

I want to convert python code to an executable but I do not want python interpreter inside. I found all program uses the python interpreter inside to run the code. I tried pyinstaller, py2exe, nuitka, but none of those didn't used python interpreter. Is there any way to convert them into executables like on C or C++?

Edit:
I need this working with tkinter

Comment: Python is a high-level language and you can't get away from the process of converting this. Even if you use Cython (which converts to C/C++) it will still call on Python components and produce large executable files as does pyinstaller. The real solution is to forgo the benefits of Python and write your code in C or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

PyInstaller, cx_Freeze, Nuitka

Comment: I've already mentioned that I am not looking for those

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).